# VIM - tabulating css

Tags: vim, vi

I have a CSS, and being a bit frenetic. I like to have my colons on the same column (I know, not everyone agree with that...).

How could I ask Vim to set all the colons on a specific column - let's say 20<sup>th</sup> columns?

My idea is to format this code:

```
body {
  3     font-family: sans-serif;
  4     background-color: #315481;
  5     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #315481, #918e82 100%);
  6     background-attachment: fixed;
  7
  8     position: absolute;
  9     top: 0;
 10     bottom: 0;
 11     left: 0;
 12     right: 0;
 13
 14     padding: 0;
 15     margin: 0;
 16
 17     font-size: 14px;
 18 }
 19
 20 .container {
 21     max-width: 600px;
 22     margin: 0 auto;
 23     min-height: 100%;
 24     background: white;
 25 }
```

like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are actually running `Vim` (you have replied in the comments to the question), I suggest installing [Align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294). With this plugin, you can apply its `Align` function to a range of lines, e.g.:

```
:'<,'>Align [:;]
```

aligns currently selected Visual area with colons and semicolons. For example, this code:

```
.container {
  max-width: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('/path/to/image.png') top left no-repeat;
}
```

will be transformed to this:

```
.container {
  max-width  : 10px                                         ; 
  margin     : 0 auto                                       ; 
  background : url('/path/to/image.png') top left no-repeat ; 
}
```

Note, you don't have to enter the `'<,'>` characters manually. Simply select a range of lines with <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd> (enter the Visual Line mode), press <kbd>k</kbd>, or <kbd>j</kbd> to select more lines up, or down, then enter the command: `:Align [:;]` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can make a shortcut for this in the vim configuration file, e.g.:

```
map <silent> <unique> <leader>ss :Align [;:]<cr>
```

With this mapping, you can call the `:Align [;:]` function with <kbd>`<leader>`</kbd> - <kbd>s</kbd> - <kbd>s</kbd> combination, where `<leader>` is a special key specified with the `mapleader` command. For example, you can define the <kbd>,</kbd> key as your `<leader>` key with the following command:

```
:let mapleader = ","
```

Then the above-mentioned mapping will be triggered with <kbd>,</kbd> - <kbd>s</kbd> - <kbd>s</kbd> (select a range of lines, and press the shortcut).